# Deactivating Conda base environment is showing another environment. How do I fix this?

Tags: anaconda, conda

Whenever I create a new Tmux session it's activated automatically with base. When I do `conda deactivate` then it shows that another environment is activated.

For example:

```
(base) user@something: conda deactivate
(env1) user@something:
```

when it used to not show anything.

When I run `conda env list` it shows:

```
# conda environments:
#
env1    /home/user/.conda/envs/env1
env2    /home/user/.conda/envs/env2
base    /usr/local
```

So something tells me that the base is set incorrectly. How do I fix this behavior?

Comment: what version of tmux do you use?

Comment: @DaniloMercadoOudalova Version 3.0a.

Comment: Can you please share your tmux config file?

Comment: What does `which python` show when (base) is present and when (env1) is present in the prompt? And what did the conda installer add to your shell rc (these may be demarcated with some fences like `# >>> conda initialize >>>`). Please edit these details into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:

Conda checks your current environment when switching environments.

When deactivating it switches back to the previous environment.

I can reproduce what you are describing by

- activating `conda activate env1`
- starting tmux, which activates the default: `base`
- with a `conda deactivate` it switches back to env1

(But as mentioned in the comments checking what is in config (tmux, conda, .bashrc etc) is important here to understand what is going on)